# Best way to integrate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} \text{d}t $

Tags: calculus, integration

Today I had an exam and I mixed up the integration by parts formula. 
The question was to integrate
$$ \int\nolimits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} \text{d}t $$

I will try solve this again with the right formula when I arrive home. I would appreciate if somebody could tell me the solution so I can double check and maybe give a hint to another way of solving this instead of integration by parts (if possible).

Comment: Hint: Write the integrand as an integral over [a,b], then switch the order of integration.

Comment: I actually asked this question a couple of weeks ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56304/integrate-difference-of-exponentials

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate then, but @Ragib's answer is different (from robjohn's) and also nice.

Comment: [Another related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828)

Answer (score 26):

I may as well give an answer:

Note $$ \frac{ e^{-at} - e^{-bt} }{t} = \int^b_a e^{-xt} dx $$ so our integral is

$$ \int^{\infty}_0 \int^b_a e^{-xt} dx dt = \int^b_a \int^{\infty}_0 e^{-xt} dt dx $$
$$ = \int^b_a \frac{1}{x} dx = \log(b/a) $$

This is a general method, and often this whole process is compressed into a well known integral called [Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Comment: nice solution you gave!

Answer (score 6):

*By differentiating under the integral sign.* Fix $a$, and let

$$
g(b) = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} dt.
$$

Differentiating w.r.t. $b$, we get
$$
g'(b) = \frac{d}{db}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} dt.
$$
Doing the differentiation,
$$
g'(b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-bt} dt = - \left.\frac{e^{-bt}}{b} \right|_{0}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{b}.
$$
Thus we must have $g(b) = \ln b + C$ for some constant $C$. To determine $C$, plug in $a$, and use the fact that $g(a) = 0$.

*Note.* I am yet to convince myself that all the steps of the proof are rigorous. I will edit my answer later if additional argument is necessary.

Comment: @Ragib Sure. I will delete my comments now (and this one in a little while).