# Showing that $\gamma = -\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \log t \,dt$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \log n\right] = -\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \log t \,dt.$$

In other words, I'm trying to show that the above definitions of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ are equivalent.

In another post here (which I can't seem to find now) someone noted that

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \log t \,dt = \left.\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\infty} t^x e^{-t} \,dt \right|_{x=0} = \Gamma'(1) = \psi(1),$$

where $\psi$ is the digamma function.  This may be a good place to start on the right-hand side.

For the left-hand side I was tempted to represent the terms with integrals.  It is not hard to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \,dx,$$

but I'm not sure this gets us anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is easy to prove that the function

$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n & 0 \leq x \leq n \\ 0 & x > n \end{cases}$$

satisfies $0 \leq f_n(x) \uparrow e^{-x}$. Thus by dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \log x \; dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log x \; dx. $$

Now by the substitution $x = nu$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{n} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log x \; dx
&= n\int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - u\right)^n (\log n + \log u) \; du \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\log n + n\int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - u\right)^n \log u \; du \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\log n + n\int_{0}^{1} v^n \log (1-v) \; dv \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\log n - n\int_{0}^{1} v^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{v^k}{k} \right) \; dv \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\log n - n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(n+k+1)} \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\log n - \frac{n}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{n+k+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} \left( \log n - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} \right).
\end{align*}$$

Therefore taking $n \to \infty$ yields $-\gamma$. If you are not comfortable with the interchange of integral and summation, you may perform integration by parts as follows:

$$ \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} v^n \log (1-v) \; dv
&= \left. \frac{v^{n+1} - 1}{n+1} \log (1-v) \right|_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{v^{n+1} - 1}{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{v - 1} \; dv \\
&= - \frac{1}{n+1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - v^{n+1}}{1 - v} \; dv
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you.  That's a nice trick at the beginning there.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem says we can interchange limit and integral on a fixed interval $I$ (ie. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_I f_n = \int_I \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$) yet here $[0, \infty)$ is transformed into : $\lim_{n \to \infty} [0,n)$, so I might be mistaken but there must extra justifications to say that we can take the limit on the bounds of the interval and on the functions $f_n$, since : $\int_0^n \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ doesn’t mean anything ? Thank you :)

Comment: @Thinking, That is precisely why I am considering $f_n$ instead of $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n$. We have $$\int_{0}^{n}f_n(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Aaaah nice, I’ve completely missed that. I understand better Antonio’s comment then. Indeed that’s a nice trick.

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$

> $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \ln\pars{n}}=
>      -\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} &=
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{n - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
=\int_{\infty}^{1}{1 - t^{1 - n} \over 1 - 1/t}\,\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}{t^{-1} - t^{-n} \over t - 1}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\pars{1 + t}^{-1} - \pars{1 + t}^{-n} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}
\bracks{-\pars{1 + t}^{-2} + n\pars{1 + t}^{-n - 1}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{t} \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}}\,\dd t
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over n}\pars{1 + {t \over n}}^{-n - 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}

---

The first integral vanishes out: Just split $\ds{\pars{0,\infty}}$ in $\ds{\pars{0,1}}$ and $\ds{\pars{1,\infty}}$ and we'll see that the 'pieces' cancels each other:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \ln\pars{n} & =
\ln\pars{n}\bracks{\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 + {t \over n}}^{-n - 1}\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ 1\,,\ \forall\ n\ >\ 0}}\ -\ 1}\
-\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\pars{1 + {t \over n}}^{-n - 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}

Note that $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + {t \over n}}^{-n - 1} = \expo{-t}}$
and $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\,\dd t = 1}$:
$$\bbox[15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\displaystyle
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \ln\pars{n}}=
     -\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t}
$$

Comment: Felix, this is an excellent development ... +1.  If I may make one observation;  the bracketed term in the highlighted box is actually zero since the integral is $1$ for all $n$.  Therefore, there is no need to pass to the limit to annihilate that term.  It is simply zero for all $n$.  -Mark

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks. I didn't go back to this answer for awhile. I just read your comment. $\textsf{Fixed}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\frac{{\Gamma '\left( x \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( x \right)}} =  - \gamma  - \frac{1}{x} + \sum\limits_{v = 1}^\infty  {\frac{x}{{v\left( {x + v} \right)}}} $$

We evaluate the expression at $x=1$ to get

$$\frac{{\Gamma '\left( 1 \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}} = \Gamma '\left( 1 \right) =  - \gamma  - 1 + \sum\limits_{v = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{v\left( {1 + v} \right)}}} $$

But since $$\sum\limits_{v = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{v\left( {1 + v} \right)}}}=1 $$

we get

$$\Gamma '\left( 1 \right) =  - \gamma $$

This would be an instant consequence of the proof that the digamma function is defined by

$$\psi \left( x \right) = \frac{{\Gamma '\left( x \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( x \right)}} =  - \gamma  - \frac{1}{x} + \sum\limits_{v = 1}^\infty  {\frac{x}{{v\left( {x + v} \right)}}} $$

Comment: But what is your proof that $\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}= - \gamma + \dots$ that does not rely on showing what's in the question prompt?