# Integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of $\ln(x)/e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Show

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x} = -\gamma$$
(gamma is Euler-Mascheroni constant).

Can anyone please prove this result?

Also

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\left( \ln(x) \right)^2}{e^x}\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: What do you accept as a form of gamma?  I.e., what would one have to develop to be believed as showing the result is the (negative of the) Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: @Eric.. Yes that is negative gamma

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}&=
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\totald{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}{\mu}
\\[5mm] & =\lim_{\mu \to 0}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Psi\pars{\mu + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{1}\Psi\pars{1}=
\color{#00f}{\large -\gamma}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

For the first integral, consider the substitution
$x = \ln(1/u)$ i.e. $u = e^{-x}$. 
This gives you
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \ln(x) e^{-x} \; dx
&= \int_1^0 \ln \left(\ln \frac{1}{u}\right)  (-du) \\
&= \int_0^1 \ln \left(\ln \frac{1}{u}\right) \; du
\end{align*}
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300531/integral-representation-of-eulers-constant) now shows the answer is $-\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log(x)\,dx = \Gamma'(1) = \Gamma(1)\,\psi(1) = -\gamma $$
follows from differentiation under the integral sign, as shown by Felix Marin. In a similar way:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log^2(x)\,dx = \Gamma''(1).\tag{1}$$
We may consider that $\Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)$ implies $\Gamma''(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)^2+\Gamma(x)\psi'(x)$.
Since $\psi'(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log^2(x)\,dx = \color{blue}{\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}}.\tag{2} $$
In a similar way:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log^3(x)\,dx = -\gamma^3-\frac{\gamma \pi^2}{2}-2\,\zeta(3),\tag{3}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log^4(x)\,dx = \gamma^4+\gamma^2 \pi ^2+\frac{3 \pi^4}{20}+8\gamma\zeta(3).\tag{4}$$