# Transform the limits of an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In this answer [Integral representation of Euler's constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300531/integral-representation-of-eulers-constant) the guy transformed the integral (4) into (5). Is there a general theorem or rule to follow? I mean, how can I do it for any integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, they had an integral defined from $t=0$ to $\infty$, and then they performed a substitution where $t=ln(1/k)$. In that case, to get the new integral limits, you substitute for the lower and upper limits like so:

New lower limit: $t=ln(1/k) = 0$ and solve for $k$. The value is $1$

New upper limit: $t=ln(1/k) = \infty$ and solve for $k$. The value is $0$

I think that's all there is to it.

Comment: I did this, but when we substitute we also have to calculate $dt$. Thanks

Comment: So, in general, these are the steps. change the variable and solve for the new one.

Comment: Well, yes, of course you should change $dt$ to $dk$. You also have to solve the integral. I thought you were asking exclusively about how to change the limits once you change the variable.