# Proving $\int_0^\infty t e^{2t} e^{-e^{-2t}} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{-\gamma}{4}$.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have been trying to prove that
$$
\int_0^\infty t e^{2t} e^{-e^{-2t}} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{-\gamma}{4}   \tag{1}
$$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I} &= \int_0^\infty t e^{2t} e^{-e^{-2t}} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{-1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(y)}{y^2} e^{-y} \, \mathrm{d}y && (e^{-2t} = y) \\
&= \frac{-1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(y)}{y^2} \left( 1 - y + \frac{y^2}{2!} - \frac{y^3}{3!} + \cdots \right) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{-1}{4} \bigg[\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(y)}{y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y  - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(y)}{y} \, \mathrm{d}y  + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(y)}{2!} \, \mathrm{d}y  - \cdots \, \bigg]
\end{align*}

But the first integral in last equation doesn't seem to converge.
Other than that I can evaluate all integrals using gamma function's

$$ \int_0^1 x^n \ln^m(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{(-1)^m m!}{(n+1)^{m+1}} $$
where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Please help me in proving $(1)$.

I literally have no idea that how it can be equal to $-\gamma/4$.

Thank you very much!!

EDIT: Actually it was $e^{2t}$ but I mistakenly typed $e^{-2t}$ if it was $e^{-2t}$ then it would be not this much tough.

**EDIT**: As [@conan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1060220/conan) mentioned in the comment that integral should be
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty t e^{2t} e^{-e^{2t}} \mathrm{d}t $$
Which is giving the required answer.

Comment: Are you sure this integral converges?

Comment: That's what I'm also thinking actually I got this integral from Romanian Mathematical Magazine...

Comment: The integral is positive while you expect it is $-\frac{\gamma}{4}\approx -0.1443$.

Comment: The left side is positive and the right side is negative

Comment: I would believe the integral is meant to be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{2x}e^{-e^{2x}} \ dx$. This integral is similar and produces $-\gamma/4$.

Comment: @Artes oh! Yeah there was a typo, there should be $e^{2x}$ instead of $e^{-2x}$ as "canan" said.

Comment: @conan yeah! Thank you cannon for correcting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @conan mentioned in his comment, I also beleive the integral is: $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{2x}e^{-e^{2x}}\mathrm d x$$

Use $t := e^{2x}$,

$$I = \frac14 \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln (t)e^{-t}\mathrm d t = \frac14 \Gamma' (1) = -\frac\gamma 4$$

Comment: Yeah! and when I was trying to find closed form as I types in question, I was getting that integral diverges. So there much be $e^{2x}$ instead of $e^{-2x}$. Thank you Kroki!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to have the correct integral.

Comment: yeah! I'm thinking to correct it, but for that I'll have to remove the whole my attempt. cuz now it is not related to corrected integral

Comment: I have edited. Please see

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a typo in the integral. I think the original integral was
$$\Omega := \int_0^\infty t e^{-2t} e^{-e^{-2t}} \,dt.$$
You can try integrating by substituting $t \mapsto -\ln(t)/2$:
\begin{align*}
\Omega &= -\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \ln(t) e^{{-t}} \,dt\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \ln(t) e^{-t}\,dt}_{I_1} + \frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \ln(t) e^{-t}\,dt}_{I_2}.
\end{align*}
$I_1$ is evaluated in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081209/1074512) to be $-\gamma$. For $I_2$, you would apply integration by parts with $u = \ln(t)$ and $dv = e^{-t}\,dt$:
\begin{align*}
I_2 &= \lim_{R \to \infty} \ -e^{-t} \ln(t) \Bigg|_{t = 1}^R + \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt\\
&\stackrel{t \mapsto -t}{=} \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt\\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{t}}{t}\,dt\\
&= -\mathrm{Ei}(-1),
\end{align*}
since [$$\mathrm{Ei}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt.$$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#5) We can simplify further to [$-\mathrm{Ei}(-1) = \delta/e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_constant) where $\delta$ is the Euler-Gompertz constant. Thus, our integral evaluates to
$$\Omega = \frac{1}{4}\left(\gamma + \frac{\delta}{e} \right).$$

Comment: Great, Thank you very much! Yeah there must be something wrong with my integral.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty te^{-2t}e^{-e^{-2t}} \, dt&=&-\frac\gamma 4,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Solution. Substitute $x=e^t$, so we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty te^{-2t}e^{-e^{-2t}} \, dt&=& \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2}e^{-1/x^2} \, \frac{dx}x
\\&=&\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^3}e^{-1/x^2} \log x\, dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, substitute $\displaystyle\frac 1x$ by $x$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^3}e^{-1/x^2} \log x\, dx&=&\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} \log x\,dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally, the substitution $x^2$ by $x$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} \log x\,dx%&=&\left[-\frac 12e^{-x^2} \log x\right]_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}x\,dx\\
&=& \frac 14\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \log x\,dx\\
&=& \frac 14\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-x}\,dx\right)\\
&=& \frac 14\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\Gamma(a+1)\right)\\
&=& \frac 14\lim_{a\to 0}\left(\Gamma'(a+1)\right)\\
&=& \frac 14\Gamma'(1)\\
&=& \frac 14\psi(1)\\
&=& -\frac\gamma 4,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\psi(z)$ is a first derivative of $\log(\Gamma(z))$ function defined as: $$\psi(z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\log(\Gamma(z)))=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1n-\frac 1{n-1+z}\right).$$

Comment: Very Nice solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.