# converging sequence of a sum and an integral

Tags: real-analysis

prove that the sequence converges 
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \ -\ \int_1^n\frac{dx}x$$

Attempt:

I dont even know where to start here. the integral gives you -ln(n)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Please use latex.

Comment: Monotonic and bounded

Comment: The integral of second term is not $-\frac{1}{n^{2}}+1$. It is $-\ln(n)$

Comment: For the convergence, observe that 1. The sequence is DECREASING. 2. The sequence is BOUNDED BELOW by 0

Comment: Hint: google "Euler_Mascheroni constant", or "gamma constant"

Comment: @sarah : this question looks identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607039/how-to-show-gamma-aka-eulers-constant-is-convergent .  One of the answers to the old question has a nice picture (unlike the first two answers to appear here).  However, I prefer ncmathsadist's answer below to the old answers because it does not require asymptotic notation, which most calculus students don't know.  I have not read Ethan's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{1\over k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over k} - \int_n^{n+1}
{dt\over t} = {1\over n+1} - \int_n^{n+1}{dt\over t} 
= \int_n^{n+1}\left({1\over n+1} - {1\over t}\right) dt < 0$$
The sequence decreases, and it is clearly bounded below by 0.

Comment: and by having the sequence bounded below by 0 and decreasing proves enough that it is convergent?

Comment: @sarah, you should know a result in the same vein as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: OK that helps thank you! @AntonioVargas

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{ \{ x \}}{x\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$$

$$\ln(n)+\int_{1}^n\frac{ \{ x \}}{x\lfloor{x}\rfloor}dx=\int_{1}^n\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}+\int_{1}^n\frac{ \{ x \}}{x\lfloor{x}\rfloor}dx=O(1)$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks, yeah I made a typo my bad, I just fixed it.