# Derivation of expressoin for hazard function (another aspect)

Tags: statistics

I'm now learning the very basics of survival analysis.

Firstly, the probability function is introduced:

$$f(t)=\frac{dF(t)}{dt}=-\frac{dS(t)}{dt}$$

Where $S(t)=1-F(t)$.

We are then introduced to the hazard function:

$$h(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$$

Subsequently, we are told that combining the previous two expressions yield:

$$h(t)=-\frac{d}{dt}log S(t)$$

How do I justify this last step, shouldn't it be something like:

$$h(t)=\frac{-\frac{dS(t)}{dt}}{S(t)}$$

??

Comment: Indeed. But these expressions are equivalent ! (review the chain rule).

Comment: This had nothing whatsoeve to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Do you pick your tags randomly rather than study what they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply evaluate the derivative to obtain:
$$h(t) = -\frac{d}{dt}\log(S(t)) = -\frac{1}{S(t)}\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$$

Comment: What confuses me is the log I think, how did "that" find its way into our equation?

Comment: @Magnus I suppose that whoever wrote that wants to use the integral of the hazard function somewhere, so it was convenient to express $h(t)$ as a derivative. To see where the $\log$ comes from, just integrate your expression for $h$ (which was $-\frac{1}{S(t)} \frac{dS}{dt}$). You remember that $\int \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dt}\;dt = \log(u)$, right?

Comment: .....no that rule is new to me. Does it have a name?

Comment: @Magnus I don't believe it has a name. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206032/what-is-the-integral-of-1-x). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071721/integration-of-frac1x-from-first-principles), if you are interested in where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

From your first equation

$$
\frac{{\rm d}S}{{\rm d}t} = -\frac{{\rm d}F}{{\rm d}t} = -f(t) \tag{1}
$$

So that

$$
h(t) = -\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \log S(t) = -\frac{1}{S(t)}\frac{{\rm d} S}{{\rm d} t} =  -\frac{1}{S(t)}[-f(t)]
$$