# Proving $\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x}\log(x)dx=-\gamma$

Tags: integration

How can I prove that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x}\log(x)dx=-\gamma$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\gamma$? Or, tell us something you know about $\gamma$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112304/showing-that-gamma-int-0-infty-e-t-log-t-dt-where-gamma-is-t