# Compute: $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a x} - e^{-b x}}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to integrate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{t} \text{d}t $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62254/best-way-to-integrate-int-0-infty-frace-at-e-btt-textdt)

Compute the improper integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a x} - e^{-b x}}{x} dx$$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62254/).

Comment: @Ragib Zaman: thanks. Your solution is very nice.

Comment: It's a particular case of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/frullani-proof-integrals).

Comment: I like to see there are so many approaches for each problem. :-)

Comment: You can't chose $C_1$ and $C_2$ (their value is fixed), but they're equal because your equality $I(a) = \ln(a) + C_1$ is valid not for a single value, but for every $a > 0$ (in particular, you can plug in $b$). Also, your integral $I(a)$ is not actually defined (there's a problem around $0$). You can fix this by not splitting the integral, and differentiating.

Comment: @ Joel Cohen: I think you're right.

Comment: @Chris:Are you allowed to interchange differentiation with integration? Check Leibniz rule.

Comment: @ Joel Cohen: right. That solution is already provided at the link given by  Ragib Zaman.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal: I did it in a hurry and missed that critical issue around $0$. :D